# my ajax and php don't fully work on godaddy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have troubled from getting all the info from `php` file to insert to `godaddy's` database and I found that it don't get all the `$_POST` because it works fine in my `localhost`.

This is my connection anyway:

```
<?php

    $test = mysql_connect("xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx","travelxxxxx","xxxxxhotel2014");
    mysql_select_db("hotelxxxx");

?>
```

and after I submit the infos, the javascript must prompt me a message that either the data is inserted or not but it's not. After clicking the `submit` button it inserts a few data on the database but don't prompt me.

Here's the image of my database: http://i58.tinypic.com/71h20z.png

And here's the website: [site](http://www.japitravellershotel.com)

Hope to help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must read about [How to turn off magic_quotes_gpc on GoDaddy](http://joomla-tips.org/configuration-tricks/how-to-turn-off-magic-quotes-gpc-on-godaddy.html)

Because I think you are using **`mysql_real_escape_string`** if I'm not mistaken.

Your table will fill with **blank** when you `mysql_real_escape_string` your data. And if you choose not to `mysql_real_escape_string` it, your data will not be inserted into your table.

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize that :)